# Testcafe - Cookie set in global test hook 'before' is not found in test

Tags: testcafe

In testcafe I want to set a cookie when testcafe runs which the tested website can use as condition to do something e.g. hide some dialogs to make tests more simple.

In my configuration file .testcaferc.cjs i set a global test before hook.

```
test: {
      before: async (t) => {
        // global before test goes here
        await t.setCookies({ testCafeRun: 'true' }, baseUrl);
        const cookies = await t.getCookies('testCafeRun');
        console.log(cookies);
      },
      after: async (t) => {
        // global after test goes here
      },
    },
```

but what i find strange is that the cookie is not present in my tests:

```
fixture('Language test')
  .page('./')
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    await t.useRole(userRole);
  });
    
    test('test 1', async (t) => {
      const cookies = await t.getCookies('testCafeRun');
      console.log(cookies);
    });
```

The cookie is found within the hook but not found in the test (the first console log has value). Is this a bug or am i missing something?

I get same experience when I use local storage.

If I however put it in beforeEach then it will work. I wonder if it is because of `await t.useRole(userRole)` in my .beforeEach. Does it clear cookies and local storage?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce the issue. It happens because Role is used in [Native Automation mode](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode). Please [create a new bug issue in the TestCafe repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml) on GitHub.

As a temporary solution, you can run this test with the `--disable-native-automation` option.

Comment: Actually I am not using native automation. And I am using testcafe version 3.0.0.

Comment: Native Automation mode works by default in TestCafe v.3.0.0 and newer. I see you [created the issue in the TestCafe repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7874). We'll continue the discussion there.